# Codeigniter - captcha for login is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, captcha

I made a captcha login it is working so far but there is two problem and that problem is that first, when your username or password is wrong the page went to blank. Second, when both of the username,password and captcha are wrong the page went blank

but when your username and password are correct and the captcha is wrong it will call the `echo'captcha is not correct';`

```
function aksi_login(){
        $data = array('username' => $this->input->post('username', TRUE),
                        'password' => md5($this->input->post('password', TRUE))
        );


        $this->load->model('m_model'); // load model_user
        $hasil = $this->m_model->cek_user($data);
        if ($hasil->num_rows() == 1 && $this->input->post('submit')){
            $inputCaptcha = $this->input->post('captcha');
            $sessCaptcha = $this->session->userdata('captchaCode');
            if($inputCaptcha === $sessCaptcha){
            foreach ($hasil->result() as $sess) {
                $sess_data['logged_in'] = 'Sudah Login';
                $sess_data['id_user'] = $sess->uid;
                $sess_data['username'] = $sess->username;
                $sess_data['level'] = $sess->level;
                $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
            }


            if ($this->session->userdata('level')=='1') {
                redirect('admin');
            }
            elseif ($this->session->userdata('level')=='2') {
                redirect('guru');
            }       
            elseif ($this->session->userdata('level')=='3') {
                redirect('siswa');
            }

        else {
            echo'username or password is wrong'
        }
    }
    else{
                echo "captcha code is not correct";
            }
    }
}
```

I think so far is because of the controller code and i have made some changes I tried putting another elseif like

```
elseif ($this->session->userdata('username')== FALSE && $this->session->userdata('password')==FALSE){
echo'username or password is wrong';
}
else {
            echo'username or password is wrong';
    }
```

but unfortunately is not working

Comment: Hi , captcha is mandatory field . if yes so please check first your captcha is right or not than after to check user name or password .

Comment: @Manishsharma you mean the value? i have already checked it for the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to check for captcha first in a separate condition then check for validation, so if you got everything right and your post values are all ok then you should do it like this:

```
if (this->captcha_validation($this->input->post('captcha')))
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->rules);
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE)
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        // your magic
    }
    else
    {
        // array of validation errors
        validation_errors = $this->form_validation->error_array();
    }
}
else
{
    // wrong captcha
    $this->recaptcha();
}
```

Now you have isolated the two checks and made it way easier for recaptcha, but more importantly you don't need to make form validation if the captcha is wrong in the first place.

...

Not sure how your code works but in `// your magic` up there put your logic like this:

```
$this->load->model('m_model'); // load model_user
$hasil = $this->m_model->cek_user($data);
if ($hasil->num_rows() > 0)
{
    foreach ($hasil->result() as $sess) 
    {
        $sess_data['logged_in'] = 'Sudah Login';
        $sess_data['id_user'] = $sess->uid;
        $sess_data['username'] = $sess->username;
        $sess_data['level'] = $sess->level;
        $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
    }
    if ($this->session->userdata('level') == '1') 
    {
        redirect('admin');
    }
    elseif ($this->session->userdata('level') == '2') 
    {
        redirect('guru');
    }       
    elseif ($this->session->userdata('level')=='3') 
    {
        redirect('siswa');
    }
}
```

Comment: so this is the login form but without level for it ??

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how you code works and what is under the hood, but i edited the answer to suit your code.

Comment: oh i see then but let me see if i can work it around

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to to rewrite your controller and use Form Validation as it is also codeigniter standard library
Check the official documentation here
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html

```
//your validation config should be something like this
public function login() {
  $form_rules = [
            [
                'field' => 'username',
                'label' => 'Username',
                'rules' => 'required',
            ],
            [
                'field' => 'password',
                'label' => 'Password',
                'rules' => 'required',
            ],
            [
                'field' => 'captcha',
                'label' => 'No HP',
                'rules' => 'rules' => 'required|callback_check_captcha'
            ],

  ];

  $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->form_rules);

  if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
    //check username & password
    //if you're sure that username is unique, you can directly get 1 data with ->row()
    $check = $this->m_model->cek_user($data)->row();

    if($check) {
       switch($check->level) {
         case '1' :
           break;
         case '2' : 
         ......
         ......
       }
    } else {
        //wrong username / password
    }

  } else {
    //show login form with view
  }

}

/*callback fro form validation*/
public function check_captcha($str) {
if(!empty($this->session->cap_word)) {
    $expiration = time() - $this->config->item('captcha_expiration');
    if($this->session->cap_time > $expiration) {
        if($this->session->cap_word == $str) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('check_captcha', 'Wrong captcha.');
            return FALSE;
        }

    } else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_captcha', 'Session captcha expired.');
        return FALSE;
    }

} else {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('check_captcha', 'KWrong captcha.');
    return FALSE;
}
}
```

Comment: but then how do i add the level for the login in there ?

Comment: if level is something that come from user data, you can check my updated answer for the 'rough' walkaround.
Check codeinigter official user guide, you'll find many function included on the library that can make you code cleaner and more readable. #semangat hehe

Comment: i see,i have been looking at the user guide i think looking the the captcha helper isn't it ?